# how to return a node with specific label in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I have extracted data from csv file with following cypher query.

```
load csv with headers from 'file:/c:/users/kannu/Desktop/author1.csv' as line
CREATE(a:Author{name:line.author})
CREATE(k1:Key{name:line.key})
CREATE (a)-[:keyword]->(K1)
```

now i want to return only Author label nodes.I want to know the cypher query.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `LOAD CSV` statement was successful you can query for all `Author` nodes using a `MATCH` statement like this:

```
MATCH (a:Author)
RETURN a
```

You can also just return author names:

```
MATCH (a:Author)
RETURN a.name AS author
```

You also might want to return all keywords for each author:

```
MATCH (a:Author)-[:keyword]->(k:Key)
RETURN a.name AS author, collect(k.name) AS keywords
```

Refer to the [Cypher refcard](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-refcard/) for more information on writing Cypher queries.